# Why 'justify-content="space-between"' not working on parent class?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I don't where and when I am doing mistake. but take a look at code and help me, that why justify-content not working on parent class.

Here is the image of my output [image: image of my output]

```css
.main-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.menu-items {
  display: flex;
}

.item-name {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

span.item-line {
  border-bottom: 2px solid var(--hr);
  width: 40%;
  height: 1px;
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.item-name {
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: var(--black-text);
  font-weight: 600;
}

p.item-price {
  color: var(--black-text);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
}

p.item-price span {
  font-size: 14px;
}

span.description {
  color: var(--light-GreyText);
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.inner-menu {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="margin">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main-menu">

      <div class="menu">
        <div class="inner-menu">
          <div class="menu-items">
            <span class="item-name">Voluptate Cillium fugiate</span>
            <span class="item-line"></span>
            <p class="item-price"><span>$</span>30</p>
          </div>

          <span class="description">
                                Cheese, tomato, mushrooms, onions
                            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="inner-menu">
          <div class="menu-items">
            <span class="item-name">Voluptate Cillium fugiate</span>
            <span class="item-line"></span>
            <p class="item-price"><span>$</span>30</p>
          </div>

          <span class="description">
                                Cheese, tomato, mushrooms, onions
                            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="inner-menu">
          <div class="menu-items">
            <span class="item-name">Voluptate Cillium fugiate</span>
            <span class="item-line"></span>
            <p class="item-price"><span>$</span>30</p>
          </div>

          <span class="description">
                                Cheese, tomato, mushrooms, onions
                            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="inner-menu">
          <div class="menu-items">
            <span class="item-name">Voluptate Cillium fugiate</span>
            <span class="item-line"></span>
            <p class="item-price"><span>$</span>30</p>
          </div>

          <span class="description">
                                Cheese, tomato, mushrooms, onions
                            </span>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="menu">
        <div class="inner-menu">
          <div class="menu-items">
            <span class="item-name">Voluptate Cillium fugiate</span>
            <span class="item-line"></span>
            <p class="item-price"><span>$</span>30</p>
          </div>

          <span class="description">
                                Cheese, tomato, mushrooms, onions
                            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="inner-menu">
          <div class="menu-items">
            <span class="item-name">Voluptate Cillium fugiate</span>
            <span class="item-line"></span>
            <p class="item-price"><span>$</span>30</p>
          </div>

          <span class="description">
                                Cheese, tomato, mushrooms, onions
                            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="inner-menu">
          <div class="menu-items">
            <span class="item-name">Voluptate Cillium fugiate</span>
            <span class="item-line"></span>
            <p class="item-price"><span>$</span>30</p>
          </div>

          <span class="description">
                                Cheese, tomato, mushrooms, onions
                            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="inner-menu">
          <div class="menu-items">
            <span class="item-name">Voluptate Cillium fugiate</span>
            <span class="item-line"></span>
            <p class="item-price"><span>$</span>30</p>
          </div>

          <span class="description">
                                Cheese, tomato, mushrooms, onions
                            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I cannot see where you are applying it

Comment: @Nikkkshit updated. check now in main-menu

Comment: `justify-content: space-between;` puts space between elements to fill up the remaining space, but in your case there is no remaining space. The two elements take up the full width (2x 50% = 100%). What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @RoToRa have look at this image now. https://postimg.cc/hXQ61N9h
The food with image are align with space-between

Comment: That image doesn't show what you expect to happen with the menu items. Try using the debugger to look at the size of the elements, or add outlines with `.main-menu, .menu { outline: 1px solid red; }`.

Comment: It's applied already. @RoToRa has mention that there no space to see that in effect, try to decrease width of ```menu```.So, you can see it in eefect.